# Pandas column appear with asterixs

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe created with pandas.

I defined the columns names and the data.
And I have something like that:

```
    EFF_ERR2       EFF3  EFF_ERR3       ...         EFF_ERR4     HV_I  
0   1.586869  25.412960  0.299300       ...         0.294916   9000.0   
1   0.985166  51.426495  0.231317       ...         0.238165   9100.0   
2   0.468122  78.285820  0.202077       ...         0.205447   9200.0   
3   0.274666  91.630341  0.190961       ...         0.192004   9300.0   
4   0.219433  92.413437  0.190340       ...         0.189163   9400.0   
5   0.202997  97.892273  0.183892       ...         0.184187   9500.0   
6   0.192679  98.152985  0.187556       ...         0.187422   9600.0   
7   0.187627  98.271095  0.186768       ...         0.186859   9700.0   
8   0.186620  98.313835  0.186297       ...         0.186314   9800.0   
9   0.183824  98.146294  0.183618       ...         0.183516   9900.0   
10  0.184760  98.277023  0.184608       ...         0.184512  10000.0   
11  0.185858  98.103539  0.185744       ...         0.185736  10100.0
```

Why does the 4th column appear with asterixs? It works because I can access the column name... But it appear in this strange way.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to increase the maximum displayed columns. Insert this before the `print` statement:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 100)
```